# Android, Xamarin: Have my app wait for the user input to allow a permission

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

this might be a noob questions but anyway:

I am asking the user to allow certain permissions. However, the app is so quick that it won't wait for the user to deceide whether to allow it or to deny it. It will just continue and then crash since the user didn't even fully read the pop up. This is the part of the code:

```
        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 23) // for phones that don't need permissions at runtime 

        {
            var GPS = new FindTheLocation(this);
            GPS.InitializeLocationManager();
            GPS.StartLocationUpdates();
        } else
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                                                                                          Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation,
                                                                                          Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessMockLocation,
                                                                                          Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation
                                                                                        }, 1);

                var GPS = new FindTheLocation(this);
                GPS.InitializeLocationManager();
                GPS.StartLocationUpdates();
                return;

        }
```

How do I get my app to stop and wait for a definitv input?

THANKS :)´
EDIT:

And yes, I am aware of maybe putting the methods into the OnResume. But I was just wondering if there is any other way round that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your app continues execution straight away after the call to RequestPermissions method. What you should do is this:

1) Override `OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)`

2) Move your GPS code there and only run it if the user has granted proper permissions.

With the above changes, your GPS code will be run only after the user has granted/rejected the permission because Android will call OnRequestPermissionsResult method only after the dialog is closed.

For a full example, take a look here: [Requesting Runtime Permissions in Android Marshmallow](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/). The most important part is *Handle Permission Request*, in the bottom half of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answear sounds like workaround and not always it may be best option to put GPS code there. What if you need ask for much more different kinds of permissions ?

I suggest to implement `ManualResetEvent` here

1) Let's say in our `DroidPermissionService` we initialize `mre` and have method to ask for permission

```
public async Task<bool> TryAcquireReadPhoneStatePermission()
    {
        _mre.Reset();
        var isPhoneStatePermissionGranted =
            ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context,
                Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState) == (int)Permission.Granted;
        if (isPhoneStatePermissionGranted)
        {
            return true;
        }
        RequestPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState, PermissionIdentifier.ReadPhoneState);
        _mre.WaitOne();
        return IsReadPhoneStatePermissionGrated;
    }
```

2) Also in same service we `Subscribe` for some kind of event that we will invoke when handle `OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)`
eg subscribe code:

```
public void Subscribe()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe(sub, string.Empty, (PermissionChangedEvent e) => 
    {
        IsReadPhoneStatePermissionGrated = isPermissionGranted;
        _mre.Set());
    }
}
```

3) In MainActivity

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults.Length != 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        var isPermissionGranted = grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted;
        MessagingCenter.Send(
            new PermissionChangedEvent(PermissionIdentifier.Location, positionStatus: locationStatus)
                {
                    IsPermissionGranted = isPermissionGranted
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that I use my own interface created to handle subscription and publish for event so I may introduce some small bugs here. But most importans is idea with usage `ManualResetEvent`

Comment: I don't understand your concept of `ManualResetEvent `. How does that relate to the question being asked? IMHO, It looks like what's valuable in your answer is the suggestion to use Publish/Subscribe to communicate from `OnRequestPermissionsResult` to whatever code needs to know the result. That is a useful technique.